# Clear back navigation stack (Android)

Tags: flutter

If I call my app using a separate activity (not the normal initial route but, for instance, by overriding `getInitialRoute()` in a secondary `FlutterActivity`), or maybe even if I have no UI at all but a plugin I call into provides a platform UI of any kind, upon returning to my code, when I want to dismiss the functionality, the root route of my Flutter app is visible for a short moment. As an example, let's consider a printing scenario:

1. my app receives a share intent
2. I catch the intent with my Android code, send it to the Dart side
3. I act upon the intent, which involves displaying the Android printing UI
4. the user finishes printing or dismisses the UI
5. control returns to my code
6. before my Flutter app goes away, its initial route displays temporarily

Item 6 happens even if I call `SystemNavigator.pop()` in my item 5. The app exits all right, the funcionality is OK, but the momentarily visible root page is a visual nuisance.

So, what I would practically need is a way to clear the back stack when I reach item 5 to make sure I don't return to the root, not even for a moment.

Answer (score 0):

I found something in the meantime that, at least for now, seems to work. It involves several steps:

- make sure you use an extra route for this activity -- this ensures that it won't be the root page but this one the navigation returns to temporarily,
- make sure the route shows an invisible page, practically an empty `Container()` -- this ensures the page will not show anything,
- start this activity with a transparent background mode (including a transparent launch theme and referencing it in the manifest) -- this ensures the page will not even re-color the background temporarily,
- use `SystemNavigator.pop([animated: false])` when your code returns from the foreign UI -- this ensures that the extra page will disappear in the end. Animated actually does nothing, as the doc describes (which is unfortunate, actually, it would be nice to be able to suppress it).

These all combined make sure that, although the extra page is technically present for a short period of time, it isn't actually visible and distracting to the user.

I'm still very much open to suggestions that provide a real solution rather than a hacky workaround, if possible. :-)